# Bluetooth Serial - Ionic 2

Tags: android, cordova, typescript, bluetooth, ionic2

I'm having an issue when I try to connect in a Bluetooth device using Android Phone. I've tested an app from Google Play and it works, but when I call connect method from BluetoothSerial native library it doesn't works. Could anyone help me please?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BluetoothSerial } from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    }

    connect() {

        BluetoothSerial.isEnabled().then(res => {

            BluetoothSerial.connect('20:14:02:18:17:84');
            BluetoothSerial.isConnected().then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            }).catch(res => {
                console.log('Fail2!');
                console.log(res);
            });

        }).catch(res => {
            console.log('Fail!');
        });

    }

}
```

> Problem Solved: I need to list the devices before I connect

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem and adding list don't give an issue.

```
connectDevice(){

      /******/

          BluetoothSerial.list()
            .then(
              () => { alert('listed'); },
              ( err ) => {
                alert('not listed');
              } )

      /****/

          BluetoothSerial.isEnabled()
            .then (
              () => { alert('enabled'); } ,
              ( err ) => {
                BluetoothSerial.showBluetoothSettings()
                  .then(
                    () => { alert('worked') },
                    ( err ) => { alert('notWorking') });
              } )

      /******/


  }
```